Invalid JWT with flutter and auth0
I’m trying Auth0 with Flutter using the auth0_flutter library.
I’m able to open the login page and get the access token like this:
final credentials = await auth0.webAuthentication().login(useHTTPS: true)
final access_token = credentials.accessToken;

I’ve created a native application in the Auth0 dashboard.
But, when I’ve sent a request to my backend including the access token, I got an invalid JWT token error.
So, I looked at the token and it’s not a JWT token, it doesn’t include any payload.
The header looks like this:
{
  "alg": "dir",
  "enc": "A256GCM",
  "iss": "https://<domain>.eu.auth0.com/"
}

If I use postman with the endpoint: https://.auth0.com/oauth/token
I managed to get a correct JWT token that my backend can accept.
What am I doing wrong? How to get a JWT token using the universal login page?
Thank you

can you clarify how you are getting the token, saving / attaching with request to backend ?

I’m following from the library https://pub.dev/packages/auth0_flutter
final credentials = await auth0.webAuthentication().login(useHTTPS: true);
// Access token -> credentials.accessToken

I've found a way to make it work by adding the audience as parameter when login.
final credentials = await auth0.webAuthentication().login(useHTTPS: true, audience: 'YOUR_AUTH0_API_IDENTIFIER');
final access_token = credentials.access_token; // Valid JWT token

